# Center divs vertically within divs

Tags: html, css

So, I have a page (height 100%) split into two rows (top half 30%, bottom half 70%).

https://jsfiddle.net/qL0s07nr/

I have an h2 tag enclosed within one column in the top half which I want to center vertically, and I have 3 other columns in the bottom half which need centering vertically too.

[image]

```
    <div class="container gb">
    <div class="row" style="height:30%; background: #f6f6f6;">
        <div class="twelve columns">
             <h2 style="text-align: center;">30%</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="height:70%; background: #d4fff0">
        <div class="one-third column">
            <div style="height: 100px; width: 100px; background-color:red;"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="one-third column">
            <div style="height: 100px; width: 100px; background-color:blue;"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="one-third column">
            <div style="height: 100px; width: 100px; background-color:green;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My css for the columns is as follows:

```
width: 100%;
float: left;
box-sizing: border-box;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
```

Full CSS:

```
.container.gb {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.column, .columns {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.one-third.column {
    width: 30.6666666667%;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

But for the life of me, I can't understand why it won't work. I am targeting the correct div, but it won't center for some reason. Any help is most appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this version: http://jsfiddle.net/leojavier/ko8wke5z/

```
<div class="container gb">
    <div class="row" style="height:30%; background: #f6f6f6;">
        <div class="twelve columns">
             <h2 style="text-align: center;">30%</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row rowb" style="height:70%; background: #d4fff0">
        <div class="one-third column">
            <div style="height: 100px; width: 100px; background-color:red;"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="one-third column">
            <div style="height: 100px; width: 100px; background-color:blue;"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="one-third column">
            <div style="height: 100px; width: 100px; background-color:green;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

full CSS

```
.container.gb {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.column, .columns {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.one-third.column {
    width: 30.6666666667%;
        display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: none;
}
.rowb {
        display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

you can try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/leojavier/ko8wke5z/

Answer (score 0):

The `div` that contains your `<h2>` does not use the full height of the row.  Add his to your css:

```
.twelve.columns{height:100%}
```

If that class is going to get used again somewhere that style won't work give that div another class or an id (or an inline style).

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox requires a flex container and flex items - it's a parent:children relationship. If you're using flexbox and presumably don't need older browser support, you can get rid of all those `floats` and specified `widths`. Your responsive layout can be done entirely with flexbox.

See this fiddle for responsive centered columns with matching gutters: https://jsfiddle.net/qL0s07nr/1/

Also, this flexbox guide is an excellent resource: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/